# How to write unit test case with sinon and tap without hitting the database?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon, stub

I have a function like this which gets data from the database by its id. I want to test this function. But I don't want to use the real database. I want to mock the database using **Sinon** library and use assertions from **tap** framework. My function is as follows.

```
function getById(id) {
  return Sample.findByPk(id).then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
    throw new EmptyResultError('No data found');
  });
}
```

where Sample is my database model.

Can anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this:

```
let sample = sinon.stub(Sample, 'findByPk') // this will stub Sample models findByPk method
sample.withArgs('507f191e810c19729de860ea').returns({ _id:'507f191e810c19729de860ea', name: 'test' })
```

`.withArgs` used to match the passed argument and return the results based on it